# How to use _.map and _.filter functions on two arrays using undersocre.js and Angualrjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, underscore.js, array.prototype.map

I am new to underscore.js. I want to use _.map() and _.filter() together to compare elements in object with an array and return an an array.

```
ReviewerStatus: { 
                  Amend: 'Amend',
                  Approve: 'Approve',
                  Reject: 'Reject',
                  Review: 'Review'
                }

vm.ReviewerStatus = _.map(appConfig.ReviewerStatus ,function (o1) { return _.filter(  data.allStatus , function(status){ return status.title == o1 }); });
```

I want to match the data.allStatus.title with each element of ReviewerStatus. I need an array of matched status but I am getting an array for matched object on each index, but I want just an object for each index.

[image]

Need a clear concept on _.map and _.filter.

Thanks In Advance